# getting Xcode to build my iPhone app on the iPhone Simulator after setting up my physical iPod to test with?

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-simulator, compilation, target

I am new to developing apps for the iPhone.  I just went through the entire process the other day of properly setting up my developer account to allow me to test my programs on my physical iPod.  Once I set it up though, I was not able to figure out how to get the iPhone Simulator working again.  I would like to test my programs quickly with the simulator and then test major revisions periodically on the physical device.  How can I adjust the target of the compiled program to test?  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the active SDK to "Simulator"

```
Project -> Active SDK -> iPhone Simulator 3.1.2
```

Comment: Wow.  I totally looked over that.  Thank you.